# tomcat cant access javascript folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat, servlets, deployment

This is my first question, so, any help will be appreciated.
I'm trying angular tutorials, and when I deploy to test the script it cant be found (HTTP 404).
i been looking for similar problems, and try solutions like the following: [image: this]
However, none seems to work.
for me is a path problem, because the angular source its pointing to an external source (https) and its working fine, but the local source, not.
I'm using eclipse, with tomcat 8 and the default servlet , just only that.
i really want to understand why this happen, and thanks for any help.
this is my web structure.

[image: web structure]

web.xml

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>listings</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Controllers</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <h1>Controllers</h1>
       <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <p> {{ message }} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my .js

```
 angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope){
      $scope.message = 'hello';
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, the most likely thing happening here is your web app runs in a non-ROOT context path. eg. `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`. If so, the context path should be prepended to `/js/app.js`, e.g. `/myapp/js/app.js`. Alternatively, you can reference it from your index page using a relative url. ie. `js/app.js` (remove the leading slash).

Also, I recommend removing all of the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` elements shown in the question from `web.xml`. Tomcat already gives you all the default servlet configs you'll need with no additional effort on your part.

Comment: hi there, and thanks for your time.
i did that, so my web.xml its just the welcome file, and i get this
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not found)" when it looks to app.js

Comment: Does using a relative path help? i.e.. `src="js/app.js"`.

Comment: thx! that one works.
The only i cant get work its telling to tomcat where look for statics resources. but with that i think i can complete the tutorial, thanks!

Comment: I forgot that, sorry!!!